# ¿Separar una matriz en grupos?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

tengo este array el cual deseo separar en grupos y agreagar un campo en cada grupo, con el nombre del grupo, eh tratado de muchas formas pero no eh podido lograrlo, espero me puedan ayudar.

```
[{"n_docu":"0102491","l_agen":"MARTINEZ LLACTA LEON","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT17"},
{"n_docu":"0102528","l_agen":"TACZA ROJAS GEORGINA SUSANA","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT2A"},
{"n_docu":"0102549 ","l_agen":"ACEVEDO QUISPE GEOVANA","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT1A"},
{"n_docu":"0102551","l_agen":"SULLCA LIMACHE GAUDENCIO","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT4A"},
{"n_docu":"0102553","l_agen":"AUCARURE VISALAYA DIONICIA","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT6A"},
{"n_docu":"0102554","l_agen":"BENITO LAZARO EUSEBIO","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT7A"},
{"n_docu":"0102555","l_agen":"ROSALES MALLMA EVER","l_subs":"PASAJE SANTA ROSA","n_via":"LT8A"},
{"n_docu":"0102556","l_agen":"MONTALVO MEZA NORMA","l_subs":"PASAJE SANTA ROSA","n_via":"LT9A"},
{"n_docu":"0102557","l_agen":"HILARIO CABEZAS ROSALIA","l_subs":"PASAJE SANTA ROSA  ","n_via":"L10A"},
{"n_docu":"0102558","l_agen":"SOTO CUEVA OSCAR  OBID","l_subs":"PASAJE SANTA ROSA  ","n_via":"L11A"},
{"n_docu":"0102559","l_agen":"PAUCARCAJA UNTIVEROS FRED","l_subs":"PSJE. SAN SEBASTIAN","n_via":"L12A"},
{"n_docu":"0102560","l_agen":"NAPAICO GUTARRA  ADOLFO","l_subs":"PSJE. SAN SEBASTIAN","n_via":"L13A"},
{"n_docu":"0102561","l_agen":"FERNANDEZ MATAMOROS FILOMENO","l_subs":"PSJE. SAN SEBASTIAN","n_via":"L14A"},
{"n_docu":"0102562","l_agen":"HUAYNATES ESTARES ASUNCION","l_subs":"PSJE. SEBASTIAN ACOSTA","n_via":"L15A"},
{"n_docu":"0102564","l_agen":"QUISPE RAMOS MARGARITA","l_subs":"PSJE. SEBASTIAN ACOSTA","n_via":"L24C"},
{"n_docu":"0102566","l_agen":"VALENTIN CHANCAVILCA ANGEL","l_subs":"PSJE. SEBASTIAN ACOSTA","n_via":"L26C"}]
```

y me gustaria separlo en grupos por el campo l_subs y obtener que esta matriz

```
[
{"l_grupo":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA"},
{"n_docu":"0102491","l_agen":"MARTINEZ LLACTA LEON","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT17"},
{"n_docu":"0102528","l_agen":"TACZA ROJAS GEORGINA SUSANA","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT2A"},
{"n_docu":"0102549 ","l_agen":"ACEVEDO QUISPE GEOVANA","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT1A"},
{"n_docu":"0102551","l_agen":"SULLCA LIMACHE GAUDENCIO","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT4A"},
{"n_docu":"0102553","l_agen":"AUCARURE VISALAYA DIONICIA","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT6A"},
{"n_docu":"0102554","l_agen":"BENITO LAZARO EUSEBIO","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT7A"}
],
[
{"l_grupo":"PASAJE SANTA ROSA"},
{"n_docu":"0102555","l_agen":"ROSALES MALLMA EVER","l_subs":"PASAJE SANTA ROSA","n_via":"LT8A"},
{"n_docu":"0102556","l_agen":"MONTALVO MEZA NORMA","l_subs":"PASAJE SANTA ROSA","n_via":"LT9A"},
{"n_docu":"0102557","l_agen":"HILARIO CABEZAS ROSALIA","l_subs":"PASAJE SANTA ROSA  ","n_via":"L10A"},
{"n_docu":"0102558","l_agen":"SOTO CUEVA OSCAR  OBID","l_subs":"PASAJE SANTA ROSA  ","n_via":"L11A"}
],
[
{"l_grupo":"PSJE. SAN SEBASTIAN"},
{"n_docu":"0102559","l_agen":"PAUCARCAJA UNTIVEROS FRED","l_subs":"PSJE. SAN SEBASTIAN","n_via":"L12A"},
{"n_docu":"0102560","l_agen":"NAPAICO GUTARRA  ADOLFO","l_subs":"PSJE. SAN SEBASTIAN","n_via":"L13A"},
{"n_docu":"0102561","l_agen":"FERNANDEZ MATAMOROS FILOMENO","l_subs":"PSJE. SAN SEBASTIAN","n_via":"L14A"}
],
[
{"l_grupo":"PSJE. SEBASTIAN ACOSTA"},
{"n_docu":"0102562","l_agen":"HUAYNATES ESTARES ASUNCION","l_subs":"PSJE. SEBASTIAN ACOSTA","n_via":"L15A"},
{"n_docu":"0102564","l_agen":"QUISPE RAMOS MARGARITA","l_subs":"PSJE. SEBASTIAN ACOSTA","n_via":"L24C"},
{"n_docu":"0102566","l_agen":"VALENTIN CHANCAVILCA ANGEL","l_subs":"PSJE. SEBASTIAN ACOSTA","n_via":"L26C"}
]
```

Comment: Qué es lo que llevas hasta el momento, lee [ask] y [mcve] para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te propongo el siguiente código, con el uso de diccionarios agrupas todas las filas que contengan el mismo valor en el campo "l_subs", una vez agrupados todos los datos puedes proceder a formatearlos de la forma que buscas, recorremos el diccionario con los datos y vamos creando nuevas filas en la matriz que contienen la llave del diccionario, en este caso el nombre del grupo y utilizando el spread operator "..." insertamos los datos que hemos ido guardando en nuestro diccionario y así logramos formatear los datos tal y como necesitas.

A continuación te adjunto una posible solución

```js
const data = [{"n_docu":"0102491","l_agen":"MARTINEZ LLACTA LEON","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT17"},
{"n_docu":"0102528","l_agen":"TACZA ROJAS GEORGINA SUSANA","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT2A"},
{"n_docu":"0102549 ","l_agen":"ACEVEDO QUISPE GEOVANA","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT1A"},
{"n_docu":"0102551","l_agen":"SULLCA LIMACHE GAUDENCIO","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT4A"},
{"n_docu":"0102553","l_agen":"AUCARURE VISALAYA DIONICIA","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT6A"},
{"n_docu":"0102554","l_agen":"BENITO LAZARO EUSEBIO","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT7A"},
{"n_docu":"0102555","l_agen":"ROSALES MALLMA EVER","l_subs":"PASAJE SANTA ROSA","n_via":"LT8A"},
{"n_docu":"0102556","l_agen":"MONTALVO MEZA NORMA","l_subs":"PASAJE SANTA ROSA","n_via":"LT9A"},
{"n_docu":"0102557","l_agen":"HILARIO CABEZAS ROSALIA","l_subs":"PASAJE SANTA ROSA  ","n_via":"L10A"},
{"n_docu":"0102558","l_agen":"SOTO CUEVA OSCAR  OBID","l_subs":"PASAJE SANTA ROSA  ","n_via":"L11A"},
{"n_docu":"0102559","l_agen":"PAUCARCAJA UNTIVEROS FRED","l_subs":"PSJE. SAN SEBASTIAN","n_via":"L12A"},
{"n_docu":"0102560","l_agen":"NAPAICO GUTARRA  ADOLFO","l_subs":"PSJE. SAN SEBASTIAN","n_via":"L13A"},
{"n_docu":"0102561","l_agen":"FERNANDEZ MATAMOROS FILOMENO","l_subs":"PSJE. SAN SEBASTIAN","n_via":"L14A"},
{"n_docu":"0102562","l_agen":"HUAYNATES ESTARES ASUNCION","l_subs":"PSJE. SEBASTIAN ACOSTA","n_via":"L15A"},
{"n_docu":"0102564","l_agen":"QUISPE RAMOS MARGARITA","l_subs":"PSJE. SEBASTIAN ACOSTA","n_via":"L24C"},
{"n_docu":"0102566","l_agen":"VALENTIN CHANCAVILCA ANGEL","l_subs":"PSJE. SEBASTIAN ACOSTA","n_via":"L26C"}];

function formatGroups(data) {
  let groups = {}
  
  for (const row of data) {
    if (groups[row.l_subs] === undefined) {
      groups[row.l_subs] = [ row ];
    } else {
      groups[row.l_subs].push(row);
    }
  }
  
  let matrix = [];
  
  for (const group in groups) {
    matrix.push([
      { l_grupo: group },
      ...groups[group]
    ]);
  }

  return matrix;
}  

console.log(formatGroups(data));
```

Comment: exelente, me da el resultado que deseo muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer así con `.reduce`:

```js
const arr = [{"n_docu":"0102491","l_agen":"MARTINEZ LLACTA LEON","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT17"},{"n_docu":"0102528","l_agen":"TACZA ROJAS GEORGINA SUSANA","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT2A"},{"n_docu":"0102549 ","l_agen":"ACEVEDO QUISPE GEOVANA","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT1A"},{"n_docu":"0102551","l_agen":"SULLCA LIMACHE GAUDENCIO","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT4A"},{"n_docu":"0102553","l_agen":"AUCARURE VISALAYA DIONICIA","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT6A"},{"n_docu":"0102554","l_agen":"BENITO LAZARO EUSEBIO","l_subs":"RESIDENCIAL STA BARBARA","n_via":"LT7A"},{"n_docu":"0102555","l_agen":"ROSALES MALLMA EVER","l_subs":"PASAJE SANTA ROSA","n_via":"LT8A"},{"n_docu":"0102556","l_agen":"MONTALVO MEZA NORMA","l_subs":"PASAJE SANTA ROSA","n_via":"LT9A"},{"n_docu":"0102557","l_agen":"HILARIO CABEZAS ROSALIA","l_subs":"PASAJE SANTA ROSA  ","n_via":"L10A"},{"n_docu":"0102558","l_agen":"SOTO CUEVA OSCAR  OBID","l_subs":"PASAJE SANTA ROSA  ","n_via":"L11A"},{"n_docu":"0102559","l_agen":"PAUCARCAJA UNTIVEROS FRED","l_subs":"PSJE. SAN SEBASTIAN","n_via":"L12A"},{"n_docu":"0102560","l_agen":"NAPAICO GUTARRA  ADOLFO","l_subs":"PSJE. SAN SEBASTIAN","n_via":"L13A"},{"n_docu":"0102561","l_agen":"FERNANDEZ MATAMOROS FILOMENO","l_subs":"PSJE. SAN SEBASTIAN","n_via":"L14A"},{"n_docu":"0102562","l_agen":"HUAYNATES ESTARES ASUNCION","l_subs":"PSJE. SEBASTIAN ACOSTA","n_via":"L15A"},{"n_docu":"0102564","l_agen":"QUISPE RAMOS MARGARITA","l_subs":"PSJE. SEBASTIAN ACOSTA","n_via":"L24C"},{"n_docu":"0102566","l_agen":"VALENTIN CHANCAVILCA ANGEL","l_subs":"PSJE. SEBASTIAN ACOSTA","n_via":"L26C"}];


const agrupado = arr.reduce((p,c)=>{
    const group = c.l_subs.replace(/ /g,"_");
if(group in p){
    p[group].push(c);
}
else{
    p[group] = [c];
}
return p;
},{});

const resultado = Object.keys(agrupado).map(g=>{    
 return [{l_grupo:g.replace(/_/g," ")}].concat(agrupado[g]);
});

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: Emeeus, muchas gracias es exactamente lo que buscaba, mil gracias

Comment: @FredyAlarconOrdoñez Si te sirvió la respuesta deberías de aceptarla para que quede como cerrada, y así de paso tanto tu como el usuario que responde os lleváis reputación.

Comment: quisas me puedas ayudar con esto quiero obtener el siguiente resultado.